# How to know the origin of a ret opcode while tracing a program

Tags: assembly, trace, low-level, ptrace

i am making a little program that works a bit like strace except that i am making it catch all the calls and also the rets.
As i can't find a way to get all the calls and ret because of indirect calls, i would like to find a way to get the function from which a ret opcode originates. Do you guys have any idea on how to do that

Comment: what instruction set is this?

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate what a `ret` does: It looks into the stack at address `%esp`, and sets `EIP` to that value. The instruction before the address at the current stack will be the `call` used to go here.

Comment: ok but as the previous instruction's size is not fixed, isn't it difficult to go backward and get to the beginning of this instruction ?

Comment: Yes, that is a general limitation of all variable-size opcode architectures - you cannot go backwards. But you do know the calling function. I'm not sure why you want to get the `call` in the first place, but the way to do that is then to disassemble the whole function from any valid point you do know, stopping at the address read by the `ret`.